# Mac OS, JDK1.7 (and 1.8) does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I need to run Eclipse Kepler on Mac OS through a JDK 1.7 (This is required by the PyDev plugin).

The problem is that although I have managed to install the 1.7 jdk and configured the eclipse.ini to use it I get the error

The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

**UPDATE**
smart people here https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues/90 claim it is enough to add JNI to the JVMCapabilities in the info.plist file like

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
   <string>JNI</string>
```

But I tried it and it does not work in my case

Comment: The file Info.plist should reside at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<javaversion>.jdk/Contents`

Comment: @Sindico -- Shan's answer worked for me, what about you?  Why don't you accept his answer by clicking on the open check-mark icon next to it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Right click on the Eclipse icon and select 'show package contents'. Inside the contents directory you'll find a file called 'Info.plist'. Scroll down to the bottom of the file till you find this

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
    <array>
        <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options,
                or add a VM found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V
          <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
          <string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Commands/java</string>
        -->
```

Notice the commented out section. Move the jdk path declaration out of the comments section. It should look like this now.

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
    <array>
      <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
        <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options,
                or add a VM found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V
          <string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Commands/java</string>
        -->
```

Last step, browse to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and check the jdk package name present there. Replace the jdk version in the above command with that.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/{your_jdk_package_name}/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Optional: On some machines you may have to close the finder after you've done all this,  navigate to the eclipse folder and click on eclipse again for it to work.

Comment: i had problem running Eclipse Luna on my mac OS X this fixed the problem for me! thanks a lot :) .. just to make sure you specify the correct path of Java on your machine use this command : /usr/libexec/java_home

Comment: I thought it will eat lot of my time when I see this error, this simple steps fixed it in few minutes, thank you so much

Comment: @Shan, it worked for me. I am just wondering why eclipse was not able to detect the correct jdk path. Maybe because I first tried to install eclipse and then I installed JRE 1.8 and JDK 1.8. I am new to Java world - that's why the order got reversed. I thought that when you install eclipse, everything will get installed. I am coming from Microsoft Visual Studio experience.

Comment: When I change, it gives me a ' "Eclipse" is damaged and can't be opened' error. Is it possible that the newer version of eclipse installations are codeSigned and changing the Info.plist fails validation. Is there a way to avoid this failure ?

Comment: My mac also does not allow me to modify the package contents.

Comment: This helped me run Eclipse Memory Analyzer.
In "/Applications/mat.app/Contents/Info.plist", I added:
<string>-vm</string><string>/Users/rrajvija/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java</string>

Comment: For me also helped to set temurin 21 version (18 didnt work)

Answer (score 15):

Just for those who may have been stuck after doing both tasks described above and still seeing the same error message: I was certain that I had downloaded 64-bit Eclipse, but it turns out I had the 32-bit version. After downloading 64-bit, everything worked!

Comment: This was my problem after updating to OS X 10.10

Answer (score 0):

I had a perfectly working Eclipse Luna, and started getting this error while trying to upgrade to Java 8 (and updating jre, jdk etc).
Shan's solution didn't work for me.
So I just downloaded and installed latest Eclipse. It's working fine. Saves the time of debugging and fiddling around.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Eclipse [Apache Directory Studio] needs to be recompiled for aarch64. Eclipse has always been a challenge on all platforms, including linux.