# Apache Directory Studio on Apple M1 Silicon

Tags: java, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have a problem run Apache Directory Studio On Apple silicon MBP M1 Max.

Error:

```
2021-12-03 12:42:07.497 ApacheDirectoryStudio[5675:42763] Error loading /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: 
 dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib, 0x0109): 
 tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),
  '/usr/lib/libjli.dylib' (no such file)
```

Looks like `Homebrew` has ApacheDirectoryStudio `x86_64` version, but Java is `arm64`.

Please help.

Comment: Use an official jdk instead of homebrew

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I was able to run ApacheDirectoryStudio by installing Java for x86_64. Rosetta 2 is required to make this work on the aarch64 (Apple M1) architecture.

To install the x86_64 version of the Java JDK via Homebrew, following command can be used:

```
arch -x86_64 brew install oracle-jdk
```

Versions used:

- ApacheDirectoryStudio: 2.0.0.v20210717-M17
- Oracle JDK: 17.0.2

Comment: So far, this seems to have worked great. You can also install ApacheDirectoryStudio using Homebrew with `brew install apache-directory-studio`.

Comment: Nice one! Install the oracle-jdk and then edit the Info.plist as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477302. This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: I tried this method and also modified info.plist as suggested by moritz.vieli but it's not working for me. I'm getting this error "The JVM shared library "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/19/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol." Any ideas?

Comment: Worked fine on Mac M1. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you install the x86_64 version of the Oracle JDK

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a current version which works.
However, you can get a working version by installing the new M1 version of Eclipse available here:

[https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-12/R/eclipse-java-2021-12-R-macosx-cocoa-aarch64.dmg]](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-12/R/eclipse-java-2021-12-R-macosx-cocoa-aarch64.dmg%5D)

Then, at the bottom of the Apache Directory Studio download page is a link with instructions on how to load the directory studio plugin into Eclipse.
This works fine. (I am using Java 17, but it should work with any java version from 11 upwards as far as I can see).

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the content of Info.plist.

```
/Applications/ApacheDirectoryStudio.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

This file contains the following commented content:

```
      <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options,
                or add a VM found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V
            <string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Commands/java</string>
            <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
        -->
```

Uncomment this line with the path to your installed JDK.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Apache Directory Studio needs Java 11 at a minimum.
But even that won't help you on M1, Eclipse won't run, with the old problem of "missing symbol" - which is actually there.

Eclipse has had this problem on and off for years, on all platforms.

The architecture of Java doesn't matter. The Intel version runs fine with Rosetta2. Remember, Java is architecture independent. It the JVM runs, the java application runs.

You may want to encourage them by commenting on my bug report:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DIRSTUDIO/issues/DIRSTUDIO-1293

There is an RC release of Eclipse for the M1. No clue how long it will take the Apache Directory Studio team to pick it up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've install Rosetta2 on my Mac, but I see no "Open using Rosetta" on "Apache Directory Studio" info. Do you know how to force app to use  Rosetta2?

Answer (score 1):

Martin M.'s solution to install the x86_64 version of a jdk worked for me.  Rather than using the oracle-jdk (because that is now licensed software) I used temurin-11.  Then following moritz.vieli's comment to modify the Info.plist got things working!  To find which path to put into the Info.plist file, run the following command to see which jdk's are installed on your mac:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V  (and append /bin/java to the path)
```

This info is found on the Apache Directory Studio website under the FAQ section.

Answer (score 0):

You can find org.eclipse.*.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.* in

/Applications/ApacheDirectoryStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins.

They are preventing boot on M1 Mac.

You can use Apache Directory Studio as an application on Eclipse.
See
https://directory.apache.org/studio/installation-in-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me in 2024 for apache-studio on M2 mac...

```
# latest jdk21 is not compatible, need to downgrade to jdk17

❯❯❯ arch -x86_64 brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/oracle-jdk17

# what is installed...

❯❯❯ brew list --versions

apache-directory-studio 2.0.0.v20210717-M17
oracle-jdk17 17.0.10

# get java dir

❯❯❯ /usr/libexec/java_home -V                                                         
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    17.0.10 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 17.0.10" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home


# update Info.plist as found throughout this thread...
# /Applications/ApacheDirectoryStudio.app/Contents/Info.plist

<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I built it from source. Here are the steps I did:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
$ brew install --cask temurin17
$ brew install maven
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/directory-studio.git
$ cd directory-studio
$ JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home ./build.sh
```

Then you can find the built `ApacheDirectoryStudio.app` application in the `product/target/products/org.apache.directory.studio.product/macosx/cocoa/aarch64` subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow solution, it worked with me.

My version:

- Apache Directory Studio - Version: 2.0.0.v20210717-M17
- MacOS 14.4, chip Apple M1 pro.

Solution:

- Install Homebrew for the Intel (x86_64) architecture, and then use it to install the x86_64 version of OpenJDK 11
- Configuring Apache Directory Studio to use the x86_64 version of OpenJDK 11 will fix the missing JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol issue.

---

Step 1: Install Resetta 2

If you haven’t already installed Rosetta 2, open Terminal and enter:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

---

Step 2: Install x86_64 Homebrew

Install a separate x86_64 instance of Homebrew in the /usr/local prefix:

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

---

Step 3: Add x86_64 Homebrew to your PATH

If you’re using Zsh (default shell in recent MacOS versions), run:

```
echo 'if [[ $(arch) == "i386" ]]; then eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc

source ~/.zshrc
```

If you’re using Bash, run:

```
echo 'if [[ $(arch) == "i386" ]]; then eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile
```

---

Step 4: Install x86_64 OpenJDK 11

Install the x86_64 version of OpenJDK 11 using the x86_64 Homebrew:

```
arch -x86_64 brew install openjdk@11
```

---

Step 5: Link OpenJDK 11

Link the x86 OpenJDK 11 installation:

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
```

---

Step 6: Update Apache Directory Studio Info.plist

Locate the Apache Directory Studio app in the Applications folder.
Right-click on the app and choose “Show Package Contents”.
Navigate to Contents > Info.plist and open it in a text editor.
Look for the following section:

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
<array>
    <string>-vm</string>
    <string>/path/to/your/jdk/bin/java</string>
</array>
```

If this section is not present, add it just before the `<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>` line.

Replace `/path/to/your/jdk/bin/java` with the path to your x86_64 JDK 11 installation:

```
<string>/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```

Save the changes and close the Info.plist file.

---

Step 7: Run Apache Directory Studio

Open Apache Directory Studio. The issue with the missing JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol should now be resolved, and you can use the application on your MacOS M1 machine.

---

Source: [running-apache-directory-studio-on-macos-m1-resolving-the-jni_createjavavm-symbol-issue/](https://security.arknet.uk/running-apache-directory-studio-on-macos-m1-resolving-the-jni_createjavavm-symbol-issue/)

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6CEE.jpg)

Answer (score -3):

Somehow version `2.0.0.v20200411-M15` ran out of the box on my M1.