# JDK Mission Control app is not launching in Mac system

Tags: java, java-11, jfr, jmc

I have installed jmc-8.2.1_osx-aarch64 in my mac OS. Java version used is 11.0.14. I have also installed eclipse in my machine. When I am trying to launch the JDK Mission Control app, its erroring out as ,
"The JVM shared library “/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.14.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib”
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol."

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753966/eclipse-jvm-shared-library-does-not-contain-the-jni-createjavavm-symbol

Comment: Could perhaps be related to these bugs on MacOS Ventura? https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JMC-7947 
https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/452

Comment: Did you try the next versions? JMC 8.3 and Oracle JDK 17

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753966/eclipse-jvm-shared-library-does-not-contain-the-jni-createjavavm-symbol).

In my case I got this error:

```
The JVM shared library "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.
```

In case it helps, in my case the solution that worked was to edit `/Applications/JDK\ Mission\ Control.app/Contents/Eclipse/jmc.ini` and add following line to it:

```
-vm 
/Library/Java/jdk-21.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

change the path as necessary [[1](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jmc8-install.html)].

**IMPORTANT**: there needs to be a line break between `-vm` and the path.

Some more notes: In my case, I do NOT have Eclipse installed. There are [two ways](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/java-components/jdk-mission-control/8/user-guide/installing-jdk-mission-control-and-supported-plugins.html#GUID-70FD5FED-5F0E-4D6C-8416-045423C2CF16) you can run JMC:

1. standalone without eclipse
2. as eclipse plugin

This solution applies in case of option 1. Not sure about option 2. What made this hard to debug is that double-clicking on JMC application did nothing. It did not even display an error. When I launched the program from terminal by running:

```
/Applications/JDK\ Mission\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/jmc
```

only then did I see an error popup saying: "The JVM shared library "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol."

**TIP**: I ran into exact same error with [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.mat). The solution again was to edit an `.ini` file - `/Applications/MemoryAnalyzer.app/Contents/Eclipse/MemoryAnalyzer.ini` this time but with same fix.