# Eclipse IDE: JVM shared library does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, ide

I'm trying to download the eclipse IDE in my macbook but every time I try to start downloading this warning shows up:
"The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/.../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol"
I've tried to change the JDK from 13 to 8 but the problem persists, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Exactly describe the steps you took.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you trying to use? The current version (2019-12) should run without issues on Java 8 or Java 13.

Comment: I met the same issue

Comment: I have the same issue on my m1 macbook. I have tried the answer below without any success. My eclipse version is eclipse jee 2020-03 and 2020-12.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the **64 bit version** of Mac Eclipse.

If the 64 bit version still didnt help you, please try the steps mentioned in the below link,

[JVM Shared library does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25486012/3253199)

Comment: I'm using the 64 version, I've tried to do those steps but I can't edit the 'Info.plist' because it's blocked, is there any way I can unblock the file?

Comment: Open a Terminal window.
Change to the place where the plist file is located:
cd ~/Library/Preferences/
Change the ownership and permissions on the file so you can read and write it:
sudo chown $USER aomDSP.plist
sudo chmod u+w aomDSP.plist
You probably don't need sudo on the second call there, but it can't hurt. You'll need administrator access to the machine to do this.
IF it still not allowing the edit by unlocking the file, you can duplicate it, edit and then remove the original file.Or Put in on the desktop,then you can change it, then put it back in the folder where it was before